# Number/Div Overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlap

I've got a div at the top right of my website which updates showing how many items in your basket. If there is 1 digit, it shows fine, however if it's double digits (10,11,12 etc..) it overlaps. Any idea how to get it to just become wider to show without overlapping?

I've provided a link to a product page so people can add X amount of products and test.

http://bit.ly/17oT6Jo

```
<!-- Live Basket (Top Right) -->
          <div id="tr-basket">
                <div class="span4 offset4">
                  <img src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>img/basket-icon.png" class="tr-shopping-basket-icon" />
                  <div id="tr-basket-count"><?php echo number_format($basket->basketCount()); ?></div>
                  <div id="tr-basket-title">
                    <p>ITEM<?php if($basket->basketCount()!=1){ ?>S<?php } ?> IN YOUR BASKET<br />
                        <a href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Basket"><span class="label label-info">VIEW</span>
                        <span class="label label-info">CHECKOUT</span></a>
                        <!-- <a href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST; ?>Site/MyAccount"><span class="label label-success">ACCOUNT</span></a> -->
                    </p>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Live Basket -->
```

css

```
    #tr-basket-count {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    color: #ef798d;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#tr-basket-title p {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: #82bdc8;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#tr-basket-buttons {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the css for the rest of the elements, like the img and the first two divs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#tr-basket-title
{
    float: right;
}
```

Add `float: right` to this element: `<div class="span4 offset4" style="float: right; margin-left: 0"></div>`

[image: Example]

Comment: He is using Bootstrap so tweaking `.span4` and `.offset4` will cause other problems.

Comment: Overriding the original definition locally is the way to go, and the inline styles are one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from a combination of using a float, followed by an inline-block and finally a block element with a negative top margin all within the `<div class="span4 offset4">` containing block.

What I would do is float the `img`, `#tr-basket-count` and `#tr-basket-title` to the left
and apply `overflow: auto` to the parent div to keep things in one block formatting context.

Be sure to reset the margins on the `p` element in `#tr-basket-title`.